# Why does dividing a int with a float result in a float?

Tags: c, cs50, implicit-conversion, arithmetic-expressions

Question why does this happen?
Is this just a C language thing?

I'm following the cs50 course.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 
 int main(void)
 {
     int testInt = 5;
     printf("%f", testInt / 4.0);      
 }
```

Output is 1.250000 -- float value

Comment: Because that's how C works.  Thought experiment: What would happen to the fractional part of your division if C didn't implicitly convert the calculation to a double?

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it?

Comment: Detail:  In C, `4.0` is type `double`.  `4.0f` is type `float`.  Both are _floating point_.

Comment: ...and in a world where it didn't, your `printf()` would simply have undefined behaviour, because you'd be telling it to print a `float` (really `double`) but actually passing it an `int`, which is UB. One possible manifestation of UB would be printing the right thing, granted. The point is that just seeing a floating-point value from `printf()` doesn't necessarily mean anything, although in this case your call and conclusion are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this just a C language thing?

The answer is "because that's how the C language defines the operation."

It is common in many languages to promote an integer to a floating point before doing an operation with another floating point value.

If it didn't work this way, there would be many accidental loss-of-precision (or loss-of-information) bugs.

Comment: Hmmm, with `int, float`, there _is_ loss-of-precision in the `int` to `float` conversion of large `int` values.  Same applies to `long long, double`.  The "If it didn't work this way ... many accidental loss-of-precision" does not hold well.

Comment: @chux: True, but you would probably choose `int` arithmetic in that case, wouldn't you?  `float` isn't a magic bullet; it's never going to give you more than 6 to 9 decimal digits of precision, and lopping off the fractional part of a calculation is almost always going to produce greater errors.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If loss of precision was a concern, code could use `(double)some_int * (double) some_float` or `(long long)some_int * (long long)some_other_int`.  The point is that "loss of precision"  is not  the strong reason for converting to a common type - it is more of a simplicity thing.

Comment: @chux: This is all part and parcel of the stated specification for implicit conversion in C.  All designs, including programming language designs, are an exercise in tradeoffs.  The great thing about C is that it still allows you to be explicit about what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

When an expression is being evaluated the compiler needs to determine the common type of operands of the expression.

So for this expression

```
testInt / 4.0
```

(where `4.0` is a floating constant of the type `double`) as the range of values of an object of the type `double` is greater than the range of values of an object of the type `int` then the compiler converts the object of the type `int` to an object of the type `double` (because it is safer to make this conversion instead of converting an object of the type `double` to an object of the type `int` at least due to truncation of the object of the type `double`) and performs the operation.

Such conversions are called the usual arithmetic conversions and described in the C Standard.

From the C Standard (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double,
> the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a
> type whose corresponding real type is double.

Comment: +1 for quoting the specific relevant section of the ISO-C standard. It might be useful to point out that the literal constant `4.0` has type `double`, per the ISO-C standard.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does dividing a int with a float result in a float?

In C, with operators like `*, / +, -, %`, when the 2 operands are of different types, a common one is found by converting the lower ranking one to the higher one.

`int` ranks lower than `float`, so the `int` operand is converted.

The language *could* have specified  `int * float` differently - perhaps as some `some_type mult_int_by_float(int, float)` operation.  Yet that approach leads to *many* combinations and still leaves the type of the result unanswered.  Promoting the lesser ranked type is simpler.

A language with N types could N*N different multiply operations.  With C's approach of ranking and conversion, it is more like N different multiply operations.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this just a C language thing?

Yes.  The TL/DR; version is that the operand with the narrower/less precise type is converted to same type as the operand with the wider/more precise type, and the type of the result is the same as that of the operand with the wider/more precise type.  Here's the specific set of rules:

> **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**
>
> 1. Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
>    types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a *common real type* for the operands
>    and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>    domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. Unless
>    explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
>    the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
>    and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*:
>
>    - First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is **`long double`**, the other
>      operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is **`long double`**.
>
>      Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is **`double`**, the other
>      operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>      corresponding real type is **`double`**.
>
>      Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is **`float`**, the other
>      operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>      corresponding real type is **`float`**.
>      <sup>62)</sup>
>
>      Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>      following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
>      - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>
>        Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>        integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>        converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>        Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>        equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>        signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>        integer type.
>
>        Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>        all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>        the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>        operand with signed integer type.
>
>        Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>        corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>62) For example, addition of a **`double _Complex`** and a **`float`** entails just the conversion of the
> **`float`** operand to **`double`** (and yields a **`double _Complex`** result).</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

If both operands are integers, then the result is an integer.  If either operand is a floating-point type, then the result has a floating-point type.